# How to put comment in a view sqlsever

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

How can I write comments in a view? In a normal query I can write them using this as example :

```
--comment here
select * from table_x where x
/*or an other comment here */
and colum_x like '%xx%'
```

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on the title.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Putting a comment into a view certainly works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/325bfb/1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add comments to views just like you add them to normal queries. For example, this works:

```
create view vw_test as

--First set
select 1 k, 'a' v
union
--Second set
select 2 k, 'b' v
```